# What is the shortcut key for transpose in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
1  2 3
4  5 6
```

---

```
1  2 3
2
3
4  5 6
5
6
```

How can I do it faster?

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1453999/edit) your post to clarify what you want. I cannot see the relationship between the rows above the line and the one below: it is not transposition as I understand it. Also, describe what you are doing now, so that we can see what might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

On Mac that would be:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: paste is ctrl+v in windows, not ctrl+alt+v

Comment: @MátéJuhász, this won't work with simple paste. Ctrl + Alt + V is for "Paste special" which then allows you to choose transpose hense "E" and "Enter

Comment: Maybe it depends on keyboard / regional settings. For me (Hungarian keyboard) CTRL+ALT+V types `@`, quick way to special paste transposing is CTRL+V then ALT then T.